# DES program that goes too many rounds.

Tags: java, encryption, des

I have this program that runs a DES encryption for the full 16 rounds, but I only need it to run 1 complete round.  My problem is that I can't seem to figure out where to cut my coding to make it stop running the full 16 rounds. Thank you for your help!

```
import javax.crypto.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

/**
 *  Performs encryption 
 */
public class DESEncryption{

    // Initial Permutation table
    private static final byte[] InitialPermutation = { 
        58, 50, 42, 34, 26, 18, 10, 2,
        60, 52, 44, 36, 28, 20, 12, 4,
        62, 54, 46, 38, 30, 22, 14, 6,
        64, 56, 48, 40, 32, 24, 16, 8,
        57, 49, 41, 33, 25, 17, 9,  1,
        59, 51, 43, 35, 27, 19, 11, 3,
        61, 53, 45, 37, 29, 21, 13, 5,
        63, 55, 47, 39, 31, 23, 15, 7
    };

    // Permuted Choice 1 table
    private static final byte[] PermutedChoice1 = {
        57, 49, 41, 33, 25, 17, 9,
        1,  58, 50, 42, 34, 26, 18,
        10, 2,  59, 51, 43, 35, 27,
        19, 11, 3,  60, 52, 44, 36,
        63, 55, 47, 39, 31, 23, 15,
        7,  62, 54, 46, 38, 30, 22,
        14, 6,  61, 53, 45, 37, 29,
        21, 13, 5,  28, 20, 12, 4
    };


    private static final byte[] PermutedChoice2 = {
        14, 17, 11, 24, 1,  5,
        3,  28, 15, 6,  21, 10,
        23, 19, 12, 4,  26, 8,
        16, 7,  27, 20, 13, 2,
        41, 52, 31, 37, 47, 55,
        30, 40, 51, 45, 33, 48,
        44, 49, 39, 56, 34, 53,
        46, 42, 50, 36, 29, 32
    };

    // Array to store the number of rotations that are to be done on each round
    private static final byte[] rotations = {
        1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1
};

    private static final byte[] Expansion = {
        32, 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,
        4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,
        8,  9,  10, 11, 12, 13,
        12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
        16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21,
        20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25,
        24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29,
        28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 1
    };

    private static final byte[][] SubstitutionBoxes = { {
        14, 4,  13, 1,  2,  15, 11, 8,  3,  10, 6,  12, 5,  9,  0,  7,
        0,  15, 7,  4,  14, 2,  13, 1,  10, 6,  12, 11, 9,  5,  3,  8,
        4,  1,  14, 8,  13, 6,  2,  11, 15, 12, 9,  7,  3,  10, 5,  0,
        15, 12, 8,  2,  4,  9,  1,  7,  5,  11, 3,  14, 10, 0,  6,  13
    }, {
        15, 1,  8,  14, 6,  11, 3,  4,  9,  7,  2,  13, 12, 0,  5,  10,
        3,  13, 4,  7,  15, 2,  8,  14, 12, 0,  1,  10, 6,  9,  11, 5,
        0,  14, 7,  11, 10, 4,  13, 1,  5,  8,  12, 6,  9,  3,  2,  15,
        13, 8,  10, 1,  3,  15, 4,  2,  11, 6,  7,  12, 0,  5,  14, 9
    }, {
        10, 0,  9,  14, 6,  3,  15, 5,  1,  13, 12, 7,  11, 4,  2,  8,
        13, 7,  0,  9,  3,  4,  6,  10, 2,  8,  5,  14, 12, 11, 15, 1,
        13, 6,  4,  9,  8,  15, 3,  0,  11, 1,  2,  12, 5,  10, 14, 7,
        1,  10, 13, 0,  6,  9,  8,  7,  4,  15, 14, 3,  11, 5,  2,  12
    }, {
        7,  13, 14, 3,  0,  6,  9,  10, 1,  2,  8,  5,  11, 12, 4,  15,
        13, 8,  11, 5,  6,  15, 0,  3,  4,  7,  2,  12, 1,  10, 14, 9,
        10, 6,  9,  0,  12, 11, 7,  13, 15, 1,  3,  14, 5,  2,  8,  4,
        3,  15, 0,  6,  10, 1,  13, 8,  9,  4,  5,  11, 12, 7,  2,  14
    }, {
        2,  12, 4,  1,  7,  10, 11, 6,  8,  5,  3,  15, 13, 0,  14, 9,
        14, 11, 2,  12, 4,  7,  13, 1,  5,  0,  15, 10, 3,  9,  8,  6,
        4,  2,  1,  11, 10, 13, 7,  8,  15, 9,  12, 5,  6,  3,  0,  14,
        11, 8,  12, 7,  1,  14, 2,  13, 6,  15, 0,  9,  10, 4,  5,  3
    }, {
        12, 1,  10, 15, 9,  2,  6,  8,  0,  13, 3,  4,  14, 7,  5,  11,
        10, 15, 4,  2,  7,  12, 9,  5,  6,  1,  13, 14, 0,  11, 3,  8,
        9,  14, 15, 5,  2,  8,  12, 3,  7,  0,  4,  10, 1,  13, 11, 6,
        4,  3,  2,  12, 9,  5,  15, 10, 11, 14, 1,  7,  6,  0,  8,  13
    }, {
        4,  11, 2,  14, 15, 0,  8,  13, 3,  12, 9,  7,  5,  10, 6,  1,
        13, 0,  11, 7,  4,  9,  1,  10, 14, 3,  5,  12, 2,  15, 8,  6,
        1,  4,  11, 13, 12, 3,  7,  14, 10, 15, 6,  8,  0,  5,  9,  2,
        6,  11, 13, 8,  1,  4,  10, 7,  9,  5,  0,  15, 14, 2,  3,  12
    }, {
        13, 2,  8,  4,  6,  15, 11, 1,  10, 9,  3,  14, 5,  0,  12, 7,
        1,  15, 13, 8,  10, 3,  7,  4,  12, 5,  6,  11, 0,  14, 9,  2,
        7,  11, 4,  1,  9,  12, 14, 2,  0,  6,  10, 13, 15, 3,  5,  8,
        2,  1,  14, 7,  4,  10, 8,  13, 15, 12, 9,  0,  3,  5,  6,  11
    } };

    private static final byte[] Permutation = {
        16, 7,  20, 21,
        29, 12, 28, 17,
        1,  15, 23, 26,
        5,  18, 31, 10,
        2,  8,  24, 14,
        32, 27, 3,  9,
        19, 13, 30, 6,
        22, 11, 4,  25
    };

    // Final permutation table
    private static final byte[] FinalPermutation = {
        40, 8, 48, 16, 56, 24, 64, 32,
        39, 7, 47, 15, 55, 23, 63, 31,
        38, 6, 46, 14, 54, 22, 62, 30,
        37, 5, 45, 13, 53, 21, 61, 29,
        36, 4, 44, 12, 52, 20, 60, 28,
        35, 3, 43, 11, 51, 19, 59, 27,
        34, 2, 42, 10, 50, 18, 58, 26,
        33, 1, 41, 9, 49, 17, 57, 25
    };

    private static int[] C = new int[28];
    private static int[] D = new int[28];


    private static int[][] subkey = new int[16][48];

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Enter the plaintext in hexadecimal: ");
        String input = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
        int inputBits[] = new int[64];

        for(int i=0 ; i < 16 ; i++) {

            String s = Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(input.charAt(i) + "", 16));

            while(s.length() < 4) {
                s = "0" + s;
            }

            for(int j=0 ; j < 4 ; j++) {
                inputBits[(4*i)+j] = Integer.parseInt(s.charAt(j) + "");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Enter the key in hexadecimal: ");
        String key = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
        int keyBits[] = new int[64];
        for(int i=0 ; i < 16 ; i++) {
            String s = Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(key.charAt(i)          + "", 16));
            while(s.length() < 4) {
                s = "0" + s;
            }
            for(int j=0 ; j < 4 ; j++) {
                keyBits[(4*i)+j] = Integer.parseInt(s.charAt(j) + "");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Encryption Rounds: ");
        int outputBits[] = permute(inputBits, keyBits, false);
        System.out.println("Decryption: ");
        permute(outputBits, keyBits, true);
    }

    private static int[] permute(int[] inputBits, int[] keyBits, boolean isDecrypt) {

        int newBits[] = new int[inputBits.length];
        for(int i=0 ; i < inputBits.length ; i++) {
            newBits[i] = inputBits[InitialPermutation[i]-1];
        }

        int L[] = new int[32];
        int R[] = new int[32];
        int i;


        for(i=0 ; i < 28 ; i++) {
            C[i] = keyBits[PermutedChoice1[i]-1];
        }
        for( ; i < 56 ; i++) {
            D[i-28] = keyBits[PermutedChoice1[i]-1];
        }

        for(int n=0 ; n < 16 ; n++) {
            System.out.println("\n-------------");
            System.out.println("Round " + (n+1) + ":");

            int newR[] = new int[0];
            if(isDecrypt) {
                newR = fiestel(R, subkey[15-n]);
                BitsDisplayed(subkey[15-n]);
            } else {
                newR = fiestel(R, KS(n, keyBits));
                BitsDisplayed(subkey[n]);
            }


            int newL[] = xor(L, newR);
            L = R;
            R = newL;
            System.out.print("L = ");
            BitsDisplayed(L);
            System.out.print("R = ");
            BitsDisplayed(R);
        }

        int output[] = new int[64];
        System.arraycopy(R, 0, output, 0, 32);
        System.arraycopy(L, 0, output, 32, 32);
        int finalOutput[] = new int[64];

        for(i=0 ; i < 64 ; i++) {
            finalOutput[i] = output[FinalPermutation[i]-1];
        }

        String hex = new String();
        for(i=0 ; i < 16 ; i++) {
            String bin = new String();
            for(int j=0 ; j < 4 ; j++) {
                bin += finalOutput[(4*i)+j];
            }
            int decimal = Integer.parseInt(bin, 2);
            hex += Integer.toHexString(decimal);
        }
        if(isDecrypt) {
            System.out.print("Decrypted text: ");

        } else {
            System.out.print("Encrypted text: ");
        }
        System.out.println(hex.toUpperCase());
        return finalOutput;
    }

    private static int[] KS(int round, int[] key) {

        int C1[] = new int[28];
        int D1[] = new int[28];


        int rotationTimes = (int) rotations[round];

        C1 = leftShift(C, rotationTimes);
        D1 = leftShift(D, rotationTimes);

        int CnDn[] = new int[56];
        System.arraycopy(C1, 0, CnDn, 0, 28);
        System.arraycopy(D1, 0, CnDn, 28, 28);

        int Kn[] = new int[48];
        for(int i=0 ; i < Kn.length ; i++) {
            Kn[i] = CnDn[PermutedChoice2[i]-1];
        }

        subkey[round] = Kn;
        C = C1;
        D = D1;
        return Kn;
    }

    private static int[] fiestel(int[] R, int[] roundKey) {

        int expandedR[] = new int[48];
        for(int i=0 ; i < 48 ; i++) {
            expandedR[i] = R[Expansion[i]-1];
        }

        int temp[] = xor(expandedR, roundKey);
        int output[] = sBlock(temp);
        return output;
    }

    private static int[] xor(int[] a, int[] b) {
        int answer[] = new int[a.length];
        for(int i=0 ; i < a.length ; i++) {
            answer[i] = a[i]^b[i];
        }
        return answer;
    }

    private static int[] sBlock(int[] bits) {
        // S-boxes applied in  method.
        int output[] = new int[32];
        for(int i=0 ; i < 8 ; i++) {
            int row[] = new int [2];
            row[0] = bits[6*i];
            row[1] = bits[(6*i)+5];
            String sRow = row[0] + "" + row[1];

            int column[] = new int[4];
            column[0] = bits[(6*i)+1];
            column[1] = bits[(6*i)+2];
            column[2] = bits[(6*i)+3];
            column[3] = bits[(6*i)+4];
            String sColumn = column[0] +""+ column[1] +""+ column[2] +""+    column[3];
            // Converting binary to decimal value
            int iRow = Integer.parseInt(sRow, 2);
            int iColumn = Integer.parseInt(sColumn, 2);
            int x = SubstitutionBoxes[i][(iRow*16) + iColumn];

            String s = Integer.toBinaryString(x);

            while(s.length() < 4) {
                s = "0" + s;
            }

            for(int j=0 ; j < 4 ; j++) {
                output[(i*4) + j] = Integer.parseInt(s.charAt(j) + "");
            }
        }

        int finalOutput[] = new int[32];
        for(int i=0 ; i < 32 ; i++) {
            finalOutput[i] = output[Permutation[i]-1];
        }
        return finalOutput;
    }

    private static int[] leftShift(int[] bits, int n) {

        int answer[] = new int[bits.length];
        System.arraycopy(bits, 0, answer, 0, bits.length);
        for(int i=0 ; i < n ; i++) {
            int temp = answer[0];
            for(int j=0 ; j < bits.length-1 ; j++) {
                answer[j] = answer[j+1];
            }
            answer[bits.length-1] = temp;
        }
        return answer;
    }

    private static void BitsDisplayed (int[] bits) {

        for(int i=0 ; i < bits.length ; i+=4) {
            String output = new String();
            for(int j=0 ; j < 4 ; j++) {
                output += bits[i+j];
            }
            System.out.print(Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(output, 2)));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for` loop that contains:

```
System.out.println("Round " + (n+1) + ":");
```

would be the primary suspect, wouldn't it? Of course you might not need the full key expansion anymore either; best check if there are bytes unused. Better replace the 16 in the for loop by a constant value so you can change it back.

Note that the code contains binary to hexadecimal conversion and I/O *right within the `permute` function. I'd expect *at most* some logging functionality in the heart of the cipher.